# Ext.js 2 checkboxes and the events are firing twice with the change listener

Tags: javascript, checkbox, extjs, listener

The problem here is that when I press either one of the checkboxes the checbox gets unmarked it sort of fires both of the change events. How can this be avoided?

What I am trying to do is have to checkboxes the possible cases are:

1. both marked.
2. one marked (vod or npvr)
3. both unmarked

In the end what I want is to establish the content_type which receives different values according to what is marked and passes it to the main form.

```html
{
                    xtype     : "checkboxgroup",
                    fieldLabel: "Content type",
                    name          : "content_type",
                    id            : "fx-form-content_type",
                    rows   : 1,
                    value  : 0,
                    editable      : false,
                    forceSelection: true,
                    queryMode     : "local",
                    horizontal  : true,
                    hidden    : false,
                    valueField    : "value",
                        items     : [
                        {
                            //xtype     : "checkboxfield",
                            boxLabel: "VOD",
                            checked   : false,
                            name      : "VOD",
                            inputValue: 1,
                            id: "fx-form-content_type-VOD",
                            value: 1,
                            labelWidth: 40,
                            listeners     : {
                                change: function (checkbox, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                                    console.error(checkbox);
                                    var isVOD = newValue;
                                    var isNPVR = Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type-NPVR").value;

                                    if(isVOD && isNPVR)
                                    {
                                        Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue(0);
                                    }
                                    else if(isVOD)
                                    {
                                        Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue({VOD: 1});
                                        console.warn(Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").valueOf());
                                    }
                                    else if(isNPVR)
                                    {
                                        Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue({NPVR: 2});
                                    }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue({});
                                        }
                                }
                            }

                        },
                        {
                            //xtype     : "checkboxfield",
                            boxLabel: "NPVR",
                            checked   : false,
                            name      : "NPVR",
                            inputValue: 2,
                            id: "fx-form-content_type-NPVR",
                            value: 2,
                            labelWidth: 40,
                            listeners     : {
                                change: function (checkbox, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
                                    console.error(checkbox);
                                    var isNPVR = newValue;
                                    var isVOD = Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type-VOD").value;

                                    if(isVOD && isNPVR)
                                    {
                                        Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue(0);
                                    }
                                    else if(isVOD)
                                    {
                                        Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue({VOD: 1});
                                    }
                                    else if(isNPVR)
                                    {
                                        Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue({NPVR: 2});
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type").setValue({});
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

Comment: Why you are tring to setValue the "fx-form-content type" on change?, which is the very checkbox group that you just clicked? If you "getValue" the "fx-form-content type" you get an array of checked itens values, no need to set anything. If you need diferent values based in the combination of choosed options, store it in a hidden field

Answer (score 1):

The setValue() of the component always fires the change event. So every time you are clicking on a checkbox, you are firing one change event there, but then inside that change listener/event you are also setting the value for the checkbox group and there is where the second change event firing happens. When you set the value of a checkbox, the checkbox changes, therefore firing its own change event.

Answer (score 0):

This can be avoided by placing the change listener to the checkboxgroup level instead of writing it at the item levels.

Comment: It's not avoidable even in that case, because it fires twice.
I already tried it and got the same result the value I'm trying to set Ext.getCmp("fx-form-content_type") get's a value of 3 in that case always.